# GCP MySQL with private IP not reachable from GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a mysql instance running with private IP enabled. When I try to connect using mysql-client from GKE container I get connection timeouts.

But mysql-client from VM instances is able to reach the server.

I verified that MySQL, VM instance, GKE all running with default network in same zone.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out Alias IP should be enabled on GKE to access SQL with private IP.